# f.collection_select order by name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do I order this by name?

```
 <%= f.collection_select :carmodel_id_equals, Carmodel.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>
```

I've looked in some search results in here but nothing worked.
p.s. this is a meta_search f.select form. Thanks.

Comment: try `<%= f.collection_select :carmodel_id_equals, Carmodel.order('name ASC').all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>`

Comment: put it as an answer so I can give you some points :) . it's working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you just have to order your search results from `Carmodel.all` by using `order` like this: `Carmodel.order('name ASC').all`

so if you put it all together it should look like:

`<%= f.collection_select :carmodel_id_equals, Carmodel.order('name ASC').all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true %>`

Read more in the awesome [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)